# How to pass NODE_ENV=production to pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have [this node app](https://github.com/FreeFeed/freefeed-server) deployed and runs fine with `NODE_ENV=production yarn  start`.

I can demonize the app using

`pm2 start npm -- start`

but then it defaults to `NODE_ENV=development` config.

And when I use

`pm2 start npm -- start NODE_ENV=production`

It still starts with `development` config.

Also I tried passing the env using a `process.yml` file

```
apps:
  - script   : index.js
    watch: true
    instances: 4
    env    :
      NODE_ENV: production
```

but `pm2 start npm -- start process.yml` still loads the development configs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: just do this..  first delete the current instance of pm2. You can do this with ```pm2 delete your_app.js```  then do this ```NODE_ENV=production pm2 start your_app.js```. This should work.

Answer (score 30):

The reason you might be facing this is because you would have started `pm2` with `development` once. Now it will use that env until you `kill` it. Following these steps should help

1. `./node_modules/.bin/pm2 kill`
2. `NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start server.js`

You can also use `--update-env`. From the [official docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/)

> By default we want that PM2 doesn’t change process environment while
>   restarting or reloading so they are immutable. If you want to update
>   them, you must use --update-env :

Comment: Well `./node_modules/.bin/pm2 kill` results in `No such file or directory`. Also not sure how to use `--update-env` with my command `pm2 start npm -- start`. I tried `pm2 start npm -- start --update-env` but it still runs in development mode. I even uninstalled pm2 and reinstall it, but then `pm2 start process.yml` still runs the dev mode.

Comment: you must have installed `pm2` globally. Just do `pm2 kill` and `NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js`

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
export NODE_ENV=production&&pm2 start server.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if you are using a pm2, the below code works for me

sudo NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js

Answer (score 2):

You just do it like this ->

```
  NODE_ENV=production pm2 restart <id|name> --update-env
```

You can check the docs here:
[PM2 - Update Env Variables docs](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/best-practices/environment-variables/)

Answer (score 1):

```
export NODE_ENV=production && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

Following line helped me! Thanks to [#mehdi parastar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9556630/mehdi-parastar) and [#abhinavd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2168941/abhinavd)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using this command (with double quotes):

```
sudo pm2 start "NODE_ENV=production yarn start"
```